# Single adjective meaning "as a mentor" or "with foresight"

Tags: single-word-requests

I had a conversation with a friend to describe how my divorced parents raised my brother and me:

> My mom just *had kids*; my father knew he was raising future adults and took care in his instruction.

I am looking for a single word to describe my father's view of raising children, i.e., with foresight or in the manner of a mentor and guide with an eye to the future. "Foresightly" and "mentorly" aren't really words. Is there such a term for this?

Comment: There must be a reason you're looking for that single word.  If it's to solve a crossword puzzle, sure, you need the word.  But if it's so you can describe your father, I don't think you gain by using an obscure single-word description over an easier multi-word description.  "With foresight" is clearer to me that "foresightedly."

Comment: Another multi-word phrase: “take the long view”.

Answer (score 1):

'Foresightedly' seems like a perfectly good word to me! But how about 'providently'?

P.S. I think it should be 'me', rather than 'I', alongside your brother in the first line :)

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for a single word to describe your father's view of raising children with foresight or in the manner of a mentor, you can aptly say that he is *mentorial* or *foresightful* (or, foresighted) in raising children.

> - **[mentorial](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/mentorial)** (adjective)
>
>   ***Serving as a mentor; advisory, admonitory.***
> - **[foresightful](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/foresightful)** in British (ˈfɔːˌsaɪtfʊl) adjective
>        ***possessing foresight***
> - **[foresighted](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/foresighted)** adjective
>
>   ***Having or using foresight.***